# Possible to configure DHCP server to only hand out IP's to PXE clients

Tags: networking, redhat, dhcp, pxe-boot, dhcp-server

Is there a way when you are setting up a Red Hat DHCP server for PXE boot to ONLY hand out IPs to PXE clients? We already have a Windows DHCP server on the network (a server which we do not manage)and do not want this to conflict with it. I have been through a lot of documentation and do not see an option to force the DHCP server to only give IPs to PXE clients. If this is possible, how can I do it and what are some other concerns that I should know about? One of my concerns is that even though some clients may not be offered an IP, they are still being routed to my DHCP server, and would not know to look elsewhere. And, by the same token, I do not want my PXE clients being routed to the Windows DHCP server that knows nothing about PXE.

Comment: Put the PXE server and clients on a separate VLAN? 

I know this will only work if you're doing original imaging in your work room. If you want to live PXE boot machines after deployment, this won't help (and hence just a comment)

Comment: Yea, we may be able to get this one another VLAN blocked off from the Windows environment. That may be the best bet. Would still be nice if DHCP had a way to differentiate between PXE and Non-PXE requests.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called `proxyDHCP`. In a DHCP + proxyDHCP PXE scenario the DHCP server provides IP parameters to "ALL" the clients while the proxyDHCP provides the PXE parameters "ONLY" to PXE clients on a complementary DHCP offer. It perfectly suits your scenario.